# Getting the below error message whenever I try to select a component template

Tags: cme, 5.3

I am getting the below error message whenever I try to select a component template within presentations in a Tridion 5.3

Currently I am using Internet Explorer 7.0, previously we had one Vertual machine having IE6 where it was working fine.

below is error message:

> **Object Expected**

[image]

I have done below activity but still it is showing error message:

1. Added my CMS url in Trusted site zone.
2. Enable "Access data sources across domains" in the Trusted Sites zone
3. Turn off the popup blocker

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do below setting in you IE can solve the issue:

Enable "Scriptlets" in the Trusted Sites zone for IE 7

1. Load Internet Explorer 7
2. Navigate to the Menu and select "Tools -> Internet Options"
3. Select the "Security" tab
4. On the "Security" tab select the button Icon "Trusted sites" and then the button "Custom Level"
5. In the "Custom Level" popup navigate to the option Scriptlets and make sure this has been enabled.
6. Press OK

Please try, I hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Its amazing. I have applied the same and error message gone. Now I can select the template from dropdown. Thanks for quick reply. I was facing the problem from last 2 week.